# How to install modules get from vendor folder

Tags: magento2

i have modules directly from vendor folder and full file with contains name and versions this modules in composer.json

When I upload only modules to vendor, and after upgrade then no result (looks like no result in  website).

How to run modules copy from vendor folder? Should I add also this code with required modules to main composer.json or something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to Upload Modules in app/code folder. When you install module with composer, then only they get placed in vendor folder.

If you have a module in vendor folder and you want to use it in another project, you can place it in the app/code folder with correct folder structure. It will work fine.

Don't forget to run all required commands.

Comment: @Jasvit Singh, thanks for your reply. Can I ask you maybe do you know Argento Theme from Swissup labs?

Comment: Never used them, reviews are good though.

Comment: Yes, but installation very hard :D  very strange and  im first  time I see  this method

Comment: do you have a moment  and could you support us in one matter? :)

Comment: Sure. happy to help

Comment: Okay ; ) I ask you here. I;ve upload all modules and theme Argento. During s:up I get: Class Swissup\Pagespeed\Helper\Config\Interceptor does not exist
I check this path: ...\Helper\Config and here I have only file Config.php  Do you know how to resolve?

Comment: You run this command first, then all other commands :- 
sudo rm -rf var/di/ var/generation/ var/cache/ var/tmp/ var/page_cache/ var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend generated/
It will remove these folders and regenerate itself when commands run.

Comment: sudo rm -rf var/di/ var/generation/ var/cache/ var/tmp/ var/page_cache/ var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/ pub/static/frontend generated/

Comment: After this: run - s:up, then s:di:compile, s:s:d -f

Comment: Please upvote the above answer if it was helpful.